# Rocket equation with Drag factor

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rockets, solid-fuel, amateur-rocketry

For the
avg Thrust of 2 kN,
burn time = 3.5 s,
burn rate= 1.4,
over the time diff of
dt = 0.1 sec
I<sub>sp</sub> = 140 sec
C<sub>d</sub> for the Ogive nose cone C-section = 0.75
Cross-sec Area of the ogive nose cone = 0.155 m<sup>2</sup>.

I am using the equations

Velocity, **$$v = I_{sp}\cdot g \cdot ln(m_o/m_f) - g \cdot t$$**

acceleration **$$ a= Thrust/V_(exhaust) $$**

height **$$h= I_{sp}\cdot g \cdot t \cdot (1-ln(m_o/m_f)/[(m_o/m_f) - 1 ]) - 0.5g\cdot t^2$$**

When I add the drag force to this calculation:
Can I use the net velocity attained as:

net velocity,**$$ v_n = v - a_d \cdot t $$**

where, deceleration due to drag, $$ a_d = Drag-force/mass $$

Similarly, how do I update the equation for the height? Do I just find the net acceleration and use equations of motion instead

**$$ h= (v^2 - u^2)/(2a_n)$$**  a<sub>n</sub> = net acceleration

Thank you all, for being so helpful with responses. I have been stuck for a while on it and the launch is nearing. :)

Comment: If this is a real project I highly recommend [OpenRocket](https://openrocket.info/) for design and simulation

Comment: Thank you @BrendanLuke15 . We are using OpenRocket however, since we are using our own motor, We cannot find a similar rocket in the software to match ours. We can match the weight by adding dummy weight but, then how do you suggest we make up the  missing thrust and burn time?

Comment: I believe it's possible to add a custom thrust curve / motor in OpenRocket